# Two PCI express video cards

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, graphics

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 desktop install on an Asus p5E3 premium motherboard. I have two graphics cards installed - A Geforce 210 and a GeForce 8800 GS. I wanted to use the 8800 as the display card and the other for GPU intensive calculations but the system has booted with the 210 as the default (this is the more powerful card so I want to swap them).

I can only physically fit the cards on the Mobo in the way that I have; So is there a way to switch which one is used as the default within Ubuntu? I couldn't see an option for this in the BIOS.

```
sudo lshw -C display

  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GT218 [GeForce 210]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:f8000000-f8ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:be000000-bfffffff ioport:cc00(size=128) memory:f9f00000-f9f7ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: G92 [GeForce 8800 GS]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:fd000000-fdffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:fa000000-fbffffff ioport:dc00(size=128) memory:fe9e0000-fe9fffff
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a PEG/PCI toggle option in the BIOS which seemed to switch which PCI-Express slot was used at boot.